# Create formula based on substrings from another cell

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, transpose, substitution

Normally forumulas in Google Sheets are no problemo.  This one has me stumped so far tho.  As input there are a bunch of lower case names which contain underscores.  How to translate that input into method names?  I can't think of a good way to do this

```
input                               output needed
api_account_registration_post       PostAccountRegistration
api_account_put                     PutAccount
api_account_upgrade_put             PutAccountUpgrade
api_account_image_put               PutAccountImage
api_account_image_get               GetAccountImage
api_account_image_delete            DeleteAccountImage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "^api_", ), "_", " ")), " ", ))
```

[image]